# Angular 11 how to initialize the Child's formgroup values?

Tags: angular, angular11

In Parent HTML have defined like this -

```
 <div class="modal-body">
          <app-addchild [childform]="element"></app-addchild>
 </div>
```

element here is the row data in JSON format, with field values.

childform is formgroup defined as @Input() with the child's Component like this -

```
 @Input() public childform = new FormGroup({
      code: new FormControl('', [Validators.required, Validators.pattern('[0-9]+')]),
      countryCode: new FormControl('', Validators.required),
      ...
    });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can assign values to `@Input` like this. You can do something like this

```
@Input() set childform(value) {
      // value is data passed to the input
     // you can do something like this
     this.gnpform.get('code').setValue(value.code);
}


public gnpform = new FormGroup({
      code: new FormControl('', [Validators.required, Validators.pattern('[0-9]+')]),
      countryCode: new FormControl('', Validators.required),
      ...
    });
```

Comment: I would change `set childform(value)` to `set code(value)` to better reflect what it is doing.

Comment: Yes, that is upto you. You can use any naming convention. It should work thats all.

Comment: Thanks Apoorva Chikara :+1: Helped.

Comment: If that worked you can accept the answer for future reference. You will be awarded for that too.